# .htaccess Remove one of GET values and redirect

Tags: .htaccess

url: http://www.side.com/en/page-1/
I need to redirect to http://www.side.com/page-1/

How to do this using .htaccess file, maybe call php file and parse string( URI )?

Comment: Lots of ways to do this - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Do you have mod_rewrite on your server? Do you want to send an HTTP 3XX series redirect or do it server-side so that the user still sees the /en/ part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*?/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```